# Error de maquetación al flotar contenido html5 css3

Tags: html5, css3

> Existe alguna otra forma de poder evitar que el contenido flotante se encime en otras etiquetas.

Para evitar que los `div` flotantes del contenido `single servicies` se encime en otros contenido utilizo este `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` como una regla al final para evitar que los contenidos `single servicies` se encime en las otras etiquetas.

Sin ella todo el contenido se encima, sera posible que en vez de utilizar `clear: both;` la propiedad `height` del cuerpo del contenido aumente como si los contenidos `single servicies` no tuvieran esta propiedad `float: left;`

```css
#services {
  padding-top: 40px!important;
  display: block;
}

.services-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.services-title h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.services-title p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.single-services {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

footer {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 180px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
  <div id="services">
<div id="container">
  <div class="services-title">
    <h2>Nuestro Servicio</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="single-services">
    <h3>Title Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="single-services">
    <h3>Title Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="single-services">
    <h3>Title Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="single-services">
    <h3>Title Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="single-services">
    <h3>Title Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="single-services">
    <h3>Title Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
  </div>
<footer>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el archivo de estilos css cambia el `float: left`:

```
 .single-services {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

por un `display: inline-block;`

```
.single-services {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Esto debería de funcionar.