# Contenido responsivo - Error de ajuste de imágenes y alineación de texto

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un error de alineación del texto, el texto no se va ajustando al cambiar la resolución de pantalla queda demasiado espacio a la derecha del texto.

El error en las imágenes no se ajustan en un orden específico, lo deseado es que las imágenes que estén en la derecha al hacer responsive la imagen salte debajo del texto. Y si la imagen esta en la izquierda, el texto salte debajo de la imagen.

El primer contenedor `div` el texto se ajusta correctamente el resto no.

Código completo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #8899a1;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
}

ul li {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px; 
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

#features {
  clear: both;
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.section-header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #262f32;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section-header p {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #8d8d8d;
 }

.media {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.box{
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left!important;
}

.boxb{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.ico {
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 64px;
  color: #72C05B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
  transition: background-color 400ms, background-color 400ms;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
}

.creative-services {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}

.creative-services ul.creative-feature li {
  color: #1b1d1f;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.creative-services ul.creative-feature li:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Blue_check_PD.svg/2000px-Blue_check_PD.svg.png);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
}

.creative-services h3, h4 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#about {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.bloque1{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.column-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.column-title:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #72C05B;
}
```

```html
<div id="features">
  <div id="container">
<div class="section-header">
  <h2 class="section-title">WELCOME TO OUR COMPANY</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <br>  et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="bloque1"><img class="" src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/feature-2.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="bloque1">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="box"><i class="ico"></i></div>
      <div class="boxb"><h4 class="h4">Title Title</h4><p>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="box"><i class="ico"></i></div>
      <div class="boxb"><h4 class="h4">Title Title</h4><p>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="box"><i class="ico"></i></div>
      <div class="boxb"><h4 class="h4">Title Title</h4><p>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div id="creative">
<div id="container">
  <div class="block"><img src="https://ioyby2hf25e3sg55t3muegr1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Switch-Onepage-Business-WordPress-Theme.png" alt="" width="600px"></div>
  <div class="creative-services">
    <h3>Unique experience</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</p>
    <h4>Features</h4>
    <ul class="creative-feature">
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="about">
  <div id="container">
<div class="conten">
  <div class="bloque1">
    <h3 class="column-title">A Little More About Us</h3>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Discover Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bloque1">
    <img class="" src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/feature-2.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar estos errores de alineación y de ajuste sin utilizar **Media-queries**?

> **Nota:** Tengo muy en cuenta que las media queries están diseñadas para el responsive design, lo que intento es limitar el uso, solo usarlas para detalles específicos, para no tener una media-quieres extensa.

Aquí unas imágenes como referencia a lo deseado:

[Imagen 1 http://inidesing.com/imagenes/responisveeeerrot.png](http://inidesing.com/imagenes/responisveeeerrot.png)

[Imagen 2 http://inidesing.com/imagenes/responsivemal.png](http://inidesing.com/imagenes/responsivemal.png)

Comment: Los comentarios que haces al final sobre las media-queries son contradictorios: por una parte dices que no quieres media-queries, para en el siguiente párrafo decir que está bien si no es mucho. ¿Podrías especificar cuál de los dos es?

Comment: Aparte, y ya como nota personal, no comprendo por qué pareces tener una idea tan negativa de las media-queries hasta el punto de querer ignorarlas por completo y no utilizarlas. Para mí, esto es un ejemplo claro en el que usar media-queries.

Comment: Creería que la única forma sin media queries es con javascript que agregue/quite clases según el ancho de la pantalla, de lo contrario lo veo imposible, ni siquiera con flexbox se podría.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No es ignorarla es evitar el uso extenso de ellas, es imposible crear un sitio responsive sin utilizarlas, pero si es posible solucionarlas sin las medias quieres, a pesar de utilizar `width` por porcentajes `%` los contenidos no encaja correctamente.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro  si podes darte cuenta el resto del texto de los contenidos al hacer responsive o al cambiar resolución de la pantalla no se ajusta como el primer div, entonces pienso que al parecer si es posible solucionarlo sin las medias quieres el problema es que no se que estoy haciendo mal para una correcta visualización.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si no estoy mal **May** intenta limitar el uso de las medias-quieres y bueno suena interesante limitar el uso de las medias-quieres seria un reto, al ejecutar el código puedo observar que las imágenes no se centran a ocupar el resto de espacio que se ocasiona a la derecha, si no se pudiera solucionar de las imágenes pero que si ocupe el texto el resto de espacio sin utilizar las medias-quieres creo que también podría solucionarse  lo de las imágenes con un solo detalle podría solucionar los dos problemas.

Comment: @Shaz Sí lo que mencionas seria así imposible, el primer contenido del `div` el texto si ocupa todos los espacios sera porque que no tiene las imágenes y si en vez de utilizar  `display: inline-block;` utilizar un `float: left;` pero creo que esto seria un problema para **May** por una pregunta que planteo no hace mucho sobre el tema [float](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24944/error-de-maquetaci%c3%b3n-al-flotar-contenido-html5-css3) vaya que es un reto imposible creo, pero es muy interesante el tema de limitar el uso de las medias-quieres.

Comment: @May Una recomendación seria jugar con el código en la consola de desarrolladores que posee los navegadores cambiar propiedad, cambiar atributos, cambiar valor, añadir nuevos estilos así tomar apuntes de que soluciones se podrían dar, ademas serviría como para optimizar código. Voy a intentar a dar con el problema pero no te prometo nada, Saludos :)

Comment: @J.Doe Gracias por la recomendación sobre lo de `float: left;` si es un problema porque en el contenido del cuerpo este ya no aumenta en altura, porque el contenido es flotante, aparte los contenidos flotantes se saben encimar en otras etiquetas y eso seria una mala visualización.

Comment: Alguna razón entendible por la que no usas media queries si justamente **están diseñadas** para el responsive design?

Comment: @MitsuGami No es exactamente que no quiero utilizar las media-quieres el diseño web responsive sin usar **media-quieres** es imposible, lo que intento es limitar su uso, es decir solo utilizarlas en detalles especificos solo imagina tener 30 enlace con el mismo problema sería una media-quieres demaciado extensa, lo que trato es ver si existe soluciones antes de ocurrir a las **media-quieres** **Nota.** Tenia una nota especificando aquello pero editaron mi pregunta, vuelvo a dar nota especificando nuevamente sobre las  media-quieres. Para evitar exactamente estas aclaraciones en los comentarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que el segundo bloque se comporte igual que el primero: copia lo mismo que tienes en el primer bloque al segundo. Sé que suena a perogrullada, pero sería tan sencillo como eso.

Haz los siguientes cambios:

- Quita los estilos que tienes ahora mismo para `.bloque1`
- Haz que `.bloque1` tenga un `display:inline-block`
- Haz que el `.bloque1` que contiene el texto (el primero) tenga un `width:48%`
- Ponle el ancho a la imagen (la del primer bloque tiene 600, así que le pondre ese mismo aunque realmente sea 457 para que los bloques se rompan a la misma resolución)

Y el resultado (he marcado los cambios con un comentario que comienza con `/* AM`):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #8899a1;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
}

ul li {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px; 
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

#features {
  clear: both;
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.section-header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #262f32;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section-header p {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #8d8d8d;
 }

.media {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.box{
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left!important;
}

.boxb{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.ico {
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 64px;
  color: #72C05B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
  transition: background-color 400ms, background-color 400ms;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
}

.creative-services {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}

.creative-services ul.creative-feature li {
  color: #1b1d1f;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.creative-services ul.creative-feature li:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Blue_check_PD.svg/2000px-Blue_check_PD.svg.png);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
}

.creative-services h3, h4 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#about {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

/*
.bloque1{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}*/


.column-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.column-title:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #72C05B;
}

/* AM - código nuevo */
.bloque1 {
  float:none;
  display:inline-block;
}

.bloque1:first-child {
  width:48%;
}
```

```html
<div id="features">
  <div id="container">
<div class="section-header">
  <h2 class="section-title">WELCOME TO OUR COMPANY</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <br>  et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="bloque1"><img class="" src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/feature-2.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="bloque1">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="box"><i class="ico"></i></div>
      <div class="boxb"><h4 class="h4">Title Title</h4><p>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="box"><i class="ico"></i></div>
      <div class="boxb"><h4 class="h4">Title Title</h4><p>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="box"><i class="ico"></i></div>
      <div class="boxb"><h4 class="h4">Title Title</h4><p>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AET Constetuer Adipiscing Elit Sednonummy</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div id="creative">
<div id="container">
  <div class="block"><img src="https://ioyby2hf25e3sg55t3muegr1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Switch-Onepage-Business-WordPress-Theme.png" alt="" width="600px"></div>
  <div class="creative-services">
    <h3>Unique experience</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</p>
    <h4>Features</h4>
    <ul class="creative-feature">
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
      <li>Features Features</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="about">
  <div id="container">
<div class="conten">
  <div class="bloque1">
    <h3 class="column-title">A Little More About Us</h3>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Discover Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bloque1">
    <img class="" src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/feature-2.png" alt="" width="600">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: las imágenes están solucionadas, pero el texto al cambiar el tamaño de resolución de pantalla, el texto no ocupa el resto de espacio que queda a la derecha, debería ocupar el resto de espacio así como lo ocupa el `div` que contiene este mensaje (WELCOME TO OUR COMPANY)

Comment: Sobre las capturas lo realice, modificando los estilos en la consola de herramienta para desarrolladores que están en los navegadores.

Comment: @May ¡Es que eso es lo mismo que utilizar una media-query o usar JavaScript! Es decirle al navegador "para esta resolución, utiliza este CSS completamente diferente."

Comment: Yo comprendo amigo :) que es imposible crear responsive sin utilizar media-quieres, lo que estoy es tratando de ver si existe una solución antes de acudir/ocurrir a las media-quieres.